# Python beautifulsoup paring html table - td data missing

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

As subject, I try to fetch the table using beautifulsoup.

http://www.hkjc.com/english/racing/Horse.asp?HorseNo=T421

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    import lxml
    import xlrd

    HorseNo = ["T421"]
    driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(r'D:\Program Files\Python\Path\PhantomJS\bin\phantomjs.exe')
    #driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'D:\Program Files\Python\Path\chromedriver.exe')
    url = "http://www.hkjc.com/english/racing/horse.asp?HorseNo=" + str(HorseNo)
    driver.get(url)
    html = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
    table = soup.find("table", {"class" :"bigborder", "width":"970"}).findAll("tr")
    print(table)
    for row in table:
        cells = row.findAll("td")

    print(cells)
```

Print(table) result is fine though print(cells) is not able to return every td in the table. Would somebody advise me further. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this below using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

HorseNo = ["T421"]
url = "http://www.hkjc.com/english/racing/horse.asp?HorseNo=" + str(HorseNo)
html = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
table = soup.find("table", {"class" :"bigborder", "width":"970"}).findAll("tr")
cells = []
for row in table:
    cell = row.findAll("td")
    cells.append(cell)

print(cells)
```

Comment: Thanks, John. Tried, same results. BTW, what is the difference in using requests and Selenium driver?

Comment: yes sorry, forgot to add the update, you can try again? requests i guess is more lightweight

Comment: Thanks, it's working. But why cell=[] is needed, for my academic interest please?

Comment: cells = [] is a list to hold your results inside the for loop, you can accept my answer if it helped you, thanks